# Display only first tick label using pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I'm using pgfplots to plot simple functions. My axis setup looks like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-30,xmax=30,
    ymin=-30,ymax=30,
    grid=both,
    axis lines=middle,
    xtick distance=4,
    ytick distance=4,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize}
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Which produces this:

[image: plot with ticks]

My problem is that many of these tick labels are redundant. **How can I only display tick labels at, say, `x = 4` and `y = 4`?**

To be clear, I want to keep the tick marks themselves, and the grid lines, I just want to get rid of the numbers `8`, `12`, etc., and `-4`, `-8`, `-12`, etc.

Comment: Welcome to TEXSE, please make your script compilable in the form of a MWE>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to do it is to add the following options to your `axis` environment:

```
xticklabels={},
yticklabels={},
extra x ticks={4},
extra y ticks={4},
```

The first two lines hide all the tick labels and the last two lines add extra ticks. The following code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=-30,xmax=30,
    ymin=-30,ymax=30,
    grid=both,
    axis lines=middle,
    xtick distance=4,
    ytick distance=4,
    enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
    axis line style={latex-latex},
    ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize},
    xticklabels={},
    extra x ticks={4},
    yticklabels={},
    extra y ticks={4},
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Nice and concise. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
  xmin=-30,xmax=30,
  ymin=-30,ymax=30,
  grid=both,
  axis lines=middle,
  xtick distance=4,
  ytick distance=4,
  xtick={-28,-24,-20,-16,-12,-8,-4,0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28},
  xticklabels={,,,,,,,,4,,,,,,},
  ytick={-28,-24,-20,-16,-12,-8,-4,0,4,8,12,16,20,24,28},
  yticklabels={,,,,,,,,4,,,,,,},
  enlargelimits={abs=0.5},
  axis line style={latex-latex},
  ticklabel style={font=\scriptsize}
  ]
  {}\end{axis};
  \end{tikzpicture}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You could use `xticklabel={\ifdim\tick pt=4pt $\pgfmathprintnumber\tick$\fi},` and `yticklabel={\ifdim\tick pt=4pt $\pgfmathprintnumber\tick$\fi},`, which would allow you to drop `xticklabels={,,,,,,,,4,,,,,,},` and `yticklabels={,,,,,,,,4,,,,,,},`.

Comment: Noted, and nice point.

Comment: Is there a way I could get the four on the x-axis to be a variable?   With the tick mark still there?

Comment: Got it!!  xticklabels={,,,,,,\(a\)}